# SpringBoot Swagger - Communication between microservices

Tags: java, swagger, microservices

I have follown this guide

```
https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api
```

to make two API REST microservices, lets say A and B.

I want to do a POST request in B, and communicate A with B, so I can GET in A the info I POST in B.
Is there any easy way to do it?

This is maybe a very simple question but I have no clue on how to do it.

Comment: This seems like you are asking for a recommendation for a library, which is considered off-topic on stackoverflow. But to actually help, I recommend you search for Spring WebClient, which you can use to perform web requests.

Comment: Hello @Rick and thanks for the recommendation, but I am not searching for a library. Im asking HOW can I code the call from service A to service B. Sorry if I wasn't being clear

Comment: You will need something to call the other webservice. I'm suggesting you use Spring WebClient for that. If you are not looking for a library you can use to call the other service, then wat are you looking for?